# Comparing Date with Other Date In Scala

Tags: scala

```
var startPeriod=2022/10
var endPeriod=2022/09
```

Here I Have to compare if `startPeriod` should be less than `endPeriod` or else print Error message.

I am trying with Below Code but its throwing below Error:

```
startPeriod.trim.parseDate("YYYY/MM").right.get.isAfter(endPeriod).trim.parseDate("YYYY/MM").right.get
```

Error:

```
User class threw exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Either.right.value on Left
```

Comment: The error means that parsing the date was not successful i.e. you got a `Left` value instead of `Right`.
Maybe the date format isn't correct? Are you using a specific library for it?

Comment: Here is a post that may help you. https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-3-how-parse-string-to-date-time/

Comment: Thank you for your help, we are using below one                                                     
       import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 2):

Always avoid `.get` when you're using `Try`, `Option`, `Either`, etc,. There are always safer approaches:

```scala
startPeriod.trim.parseDate("YYYY/MM").flatMap { start => 
  endPeriod.trim.parseDate("YYYY/MM").map { end => 
    start.isAfter(end)
  }
}.toOption
// result would be Option[Boolean]
```

Anyway, about your actual problem, I'm not sure what is the library you're using, but `2022/10` is not a date, date is a combination of year, month of year and day of month. Your value is a what's so called `YearMonth`:

```scala
import java.time._
import java.time.format._

val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM")
Try(YearMonth.parse(startPeriod, formatter)).flatMap { start => 
  Try(YearMonth.parse(endPeriod, formatter)).map { end => 
    start.isAfter(end)
  }
}
// here you have a Try[Boolean], you can convert it to option, getOrElse on it and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to use the above method its not working for me